# Is it possible to add languages to sys.syslanguages in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Can I add another language to SQL Server by add a new row to sys.syslanguages and use it by

```
set language new_language_name
```

Answer (score 0):

NO, you cannot update the system tables.

Comment: Can you give us a reference of this ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're trying to do but I've added additional languages to SQL Server using this method in the past: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345188.aspx

This method pertains to adding fulltext support for additional languages. I don't actually know any any other reasons for adding another language (vs downloading a localized version of sql server) so let me know more of what you're trying to do if I'm off here.