# SQL SELECT Month name in Ukrainian language

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016

I try to do something like this. But Ukrainian language not exists in sys.syslanguages.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.syslanguages

SET LANGUAGE Ukrainian
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE()) AS 'MonthName'
```

Any ideas how to select month name in Ukrainian?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe check this post answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9669427/is-it-possible-to-add-languages-to-sys-syslanguages-in-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a globalization/localization infrastructure by yourself. For example, you can create table with the following column:

```
Language
Localization
LiteralID
Literal
```

Then insert the translation of the months in it:

```
INSERT INTO ...
VALUES ('uk', '', 'January', N'січень')
      ,('uk', '', 'February', N'лютого') 
      ...
```

Then you have to create function which is translating a literal ID to the current user language and use it to translate things depending on user localization settings.

---

For months particualary, you can do this:

```
SET LANGUAGE Spanish

SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE())
```

where language is get from `sys.syslanguages`.